# Using paypal pro for repeat nonrecurring charges

Tags: transactions, paypal, repeat

Is there anyway to use paypal pro to allow a customer to make repeat purchases without setting up a recurring payment.  The use case is a customer who does not have a paypal account enters payment info once for a purchase.  When they return to the website, it would be nice if they didn't have to enter payment details again.  This is possible for recurring payments but I see no way of doing this for repeat one-time transactions.

Comment: Please explain the programming part of this question.

Comment: Since I do not have a pci compliant web server, and I cannot save credit cards on my server, I would like to use paypal in a similar way as I would use recurring payments with paypal.  In particular, I'm trying to save a customers credit card info in some way so that they do not have to retype payment info.  Suggestions?

Comment: did you figure out a way to do this? it must be possible somehow as skype do it to automatically top up the credit on your account for example. interested to here any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar functionality and found [DoReferenceTransaction API operation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoReferenceTransaction). It allows to use details from another transaction which is specified by *ReferenceId* parameter. For instance one can use *TransactionId* returned by *DoDirectPayment* as *ReferenceId* for *DoReferenceTransaction*